# UILocalNotification Repeat

Tags: objective-c, notifications, localnotification

I want repeat on the Every Sunday and Monday

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9):

Try setting 2 notifications, one with a Sunday `fireDate` and the other with a Monday `fireDate` and set both repeatIntervals to `NSWeekCalendarUnit`